# How to add variables of multiple objects

Tags: python-3.x, oop, methods

I know to add objects of same class using special methods like following code:

```
class cal(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return cal(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)


def Main():
    obj1 = cal(2, 3)

    obj2 = cal(4, 5)

    obj3 = obj1 + obj2

    print(obj4.x)
    print(obj4.y)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Here, only two objects are added. But if there were more then two objects like `obj4 = obj1 + obj2 + obj3`, how to add them?

Comment: Try it? `obj4 = obj1 + obj2 + obj3` is the same as `obj4 = (obj1 + obj2) + obj3`. `obj1 + obj2` yields a valid `cal` object, so you can add `obj3` to that. Where's your problem?

Comment: Ok. I didnt tried that. It works. I thought there should be something other than `self` and `other` in `__add__` method. Thanks